# Voice Recording while music playing at the same time using AudioUnit in the iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio-recording, audiounit, audio-player

I am trying to record voice to file while playing music.
I think AudioUnit is good choice for doing this, but I cannot find any simple sample code for doing this. Any advice or help?